# WordPress cron creation during plugin installation results with initial execution

Tags: wp-cron

I'm currently developing a plugin which uses WP cron. During the installation of the plugin, I'm creating 2 needed cron jobs with a timestamp of midnight -2 and a and midnight -1 hour, since job 2 should only run 1 hour after job 1.

Even when using a timestamp during creation which is 3-4 hours in the future, it seems like that both functions are getting initially executed directly after the plugin install / update, which results in a lot of issues.

```
wp_schedule_event( strtotime( 'midnight' ) + ( - 2 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS ), 'daily', 'test1' );

wp_schedule_event( strtotime( 'midnight' ) + ( - 1 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS ), 'daily', 'test2' );
```

Any idea how to prevent an initial execution of each event during creation?

Comment: This shouldn't happen due to cron. Are you sure you are not firing those functions elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtotime( 'midnight' )` will give you midnight *for today*, which has already happened! You want midnight *for tomorrow*.

e.g. `date( 'F jS H:i:s', strtotime( 'midnight' ) )` on July 19th is `July 19th 00:00:00`

However, `date( 'F jS H:i:s', strtotime( 'tomorrow midnight' ) )` would be `July 20th 00:00:00`

...which is what you want! So just use `tomorrow midnight` instead.

Comment: Makes totally sense. Thanks for this hint!